# Dynamically add option to chosen select multiple JQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-chosen

I want to add the text that a user inputs in the text field of a chosen select multiple input as an option, and automatically select it, all of this when the option doesn't exists, if the option exists, then I would like to select it. So far I have manage to do this:

```
Chosen.prototype.add_text_as_option = function () {
    $('#id_select').append(
        $('<option>')
                .html(this.search_field.val())
                .attr('selected', 'selected')
                .attr('value', 0)
    );
    $('#id_select').trigger("liszt:updated");
    return false;
};
```

I call this function whenever the users presses enter while the input field is in focus within the `keydown_check` function.

I have two problems:

- Top priority, when the user presses enter and has typed a substring of an option, the option won't get selected, but the substring text will be added and selected. Not what I want.

For instance: If I have the option "foo", and start typing "fo", chosen will mark the first
option as candidate ("foo"), so if I press enter, it should be selected, but instead, what happens is that "fo" is added as an option and selected, when I actually wanted to select "foo".

If I select "foo" with a click, then everything works fine. The option chosen marks is selected and the substring text is taken as part of the option.

How can I add a non existent option to chosen, without loosing all the original functionality?

- How can I access the select multiple field I initilized whith chosen inside the chosen plugin? As you can see in the code above, the id of the select multiple field is hardcoded. I want to do this to be able to refresh the select when the user adds a new option.
- The functionality that I'm looking for is very similar to the skills widget of [linkedin](http://linkedin.com)

Comment: You seem to be saying that when the user enters a value that matches the beginning of an existing option then that option should be selected, but what if it matches more than one option? (E.g., "fo" would match "food" and "football" - select both?)

Comment: I just want to let the user select what he wants, and in the case he desires to, add a new option.

Comment: What @nnnnnn says, +1, but also what if you wanted to add "fo"? I think the issue is more conceptual than anything else. It seems that you need mechanism(s) to (a) add exactly what you've typed regardless of existing options, (b) add a singleton matching option, and (c) add an option selected from multiple matches.

Comment: Sorry, that's not quite right. (b) and (c) should read "(b) select a singleton matching option, and (c) select an option from multiple matches".

Comment: The linkedin widget that I mention in my question explains well what I expecto from mine

Answer (score 1):

You should try out the select2 plugin which is based off of chosen plugin but it works well with adding elements dynamically.

Heres the link: http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Look at the example for auto-tokenization I think that might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I needed this today so I wrote something like this:

```
$(function() {
    // form id
    $('#newtag').alajax({
        // data contains json_encoded array, sent from server
        success: function(data) {
            // this is missing in alajax plugin
            data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            // create new option for original select
            var opt = document.createElement("OPTION");
            opt.value = data.id;
            opt.text = data.name;
            opt.selected = true;
            // check if the same value already exists
            var el = $('#tags option[value="' + opt.value + '"]');
            if( !el.size() ) {
                // no? append it and update chosen-select field
                $('#tags').append( opt ).trigger("chosen:updated");
            } else {
                // it does? check if it's already selected
                if(!el[0].selected) {
                    // adding already existent element in selection
                    el[0].selected = true;
                    $('#tags').trigger("chosen:updated");
                } else {
                    alert("Already selected and added.");
                }
            }


        }
    })
});
```

"#"newtag is a form, ".alajax" is a [plugin](https://github.com/alaabadran/ALAJAX) that sends form data in async way and returns server's response in JSON format. In the controller I check if a tag exists otherwise I create it. In response I five "jsoned" tag object.

Answer (score 1):

I created a jsfiddle of jquery chosen which takes text and create as option. In earlier version of jquery chosen have facility create option.

```
create_option: true;
persistent_create_option: true;
skip_no_results: true;
```

You can use this code:

```
$('#id_select').chosen({
    width: '100%', 
    create_option: true, 
    persistent_create_option: true, 
    skip_no_results: true
});
```

jsfiddle link:  https://jsfiddle.net/n4nrqtek/

Answer (score 0):

just call it keyup_check 
keydown_check is called before the pressed letter is initialized
unlike keyup_check

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution multiple select

```
var str_array = ['css','html'];
$("#id_select").val(str_array).trigger("chosen:updated");
```