# chosen.js : create_option parameter not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

I want to add values on the fly in chosen.js plugin.

github.com/harvesthq/chosen

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/pull/166) but its not working. I searched in all the available options as well but its not listed [there](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html).

My JS is

```
$('.chosen-select').chosen({
    add_new_options: true,
    disable_search_threshold : 5,
    no_results_text : "Oops, nothing found!"    
});
```

Am I missing something? Any other parameter is required here? Why is that missing from the available option list?

Comment: Take full solution from below links stackoverflow link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731932

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same process. The link to fork you mentioned (chosen/pull/166) is merged into chosen root as chosen 1.4.2 and is available for download.

Following steps should work:

- Download Chosen 1.4.2 from: 
  https://github.com/koenpunt/chosen/releases
- If you already have Chosen in your project, replace chosen.jquery.js, chosen.jquery.min.js, and chosen.css
- Use the following code to use the new create_option:

  ```
  $(function() {                 
  $(".chzn-select").chosen({
      create_option: true,            
      skip_no_results: true
  }); });
  ```

Code reference: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/pull/166

Comment: Thanks for the details. This feature seems lost in the newer version 1.6.2.